# Is it possible to use a min heap as a max heap?

Tags: heap, heapsort, min-heap, max-heap

I've implemented a minHeap class so I am curious if, without modifying the code, it would be possible to use the minHeap class as a max heap?

Comment: What language are you referring to? please add tags

Comment: @Sean: This seems like an algo question, thus language-agnostic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just flip the sign of all your values before you put them into the heap, and again as you take them out of the heap.